# Rengenerating Provisional profile, distribution certificate and APNS certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new to certificate generation. We have our app(Xamarin.Forms-iOS) in production already and planned for another production release this month end.

Provisional profile and distribution profile are expiring by May end.
And APNS certificate is going to expire by June end.

Note: All the above certificates are generated from team-members's system (CSR).

Can I re-generate provisional profile and distribution certificate  this month from my system and release build to production? Will that affect existing app or something?

And during June, if I regenerate APNS certificate from my system and upload it to azure hub. Will the production app continues to work fine (receive push notification)?

Is there any dependency between CSR or APNS dependency with other certificate?

Note: I will be re-generating certificates from my machine for the same bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Provisional profile and distribution profile are expiring by May end***, means your account will also expire. Make sure you renew them.

After renew, just renew the profiles. **Don't create new.**

***APNS certificate is going to expire by June end.***, means when you make new APNS (certificates), just go and update provision profile. No need to create new provisional profile.

***And during June, if I regenerate APNS certificate from my system and upload it to azure hub. Will the production app continues to work fine (receive push notification)?*** - Yes, just after you make new/renew APNS, re-generate provision profile as said above. That's it.

Comment: thanks, I am in an assumption that APNS certificate has no relation to provisional profile. When I make new/renew APNS by June(revoke older one, create new one and upload it to Azure hub), I don't have to regenerate provisional profile . Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you don't have to regenerate, but you have to renew provision profile which is important step. (just edit current provision profile and save so that new apns info gets stored in current provision profile)